# How do I get a three digit range starting from 000 in scala? ex List.range(000, 200) output : List(000, 001, 002.... ,199)

Tags: scala

I am writing a scala program to read 200 parquet files whose filenames have a pattern. I thought of using the range function but unfortunately in the range 000 is considered as 0.

```
val x = List.range(000, 200)
println(x(0))
```

The print statement yeilds 0 as the output. 
I want the list to have `(000, 001, 002, 003 ......., 198, 199)`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this, but one of the simplest would be to use the `f` string interpolator:

```
val ids: IndexedSeq[String] = (0 until 200).map(i => f"$i%03d")
```

Which looks like this:

```
scala> ids.take(5).foreach(println)
000
001
002
003
004
```

The `f` part indicates that any variables in the following string literal should be interpolated with the provided [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). In this case our integer id is called `i`, and `$i%03d` says "interpolate the integral value `i` with width 3 and leading zeros if necessary".